# for loops and if conditional applied to data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

If have two csv data frames data1 and data2 of dimension/size n1*n2 and m1*m2. I would like to create a new data frame consisting of differences: If (and only if)

```
    data1[i,1] = data2[j,1] & data1[i,3] = data2[j,3]
```

then I want to consider

```
    difference[i,z] <- abs(data1[i,x]-data2[i,y])
```

Is it possible to this in a simple manner, for instance using for/if?

```
  difference <- matrix(nrow = max{n1,m1}, ncol = 3)
  for (i in 1:n1) {
    for (j in 1:m1) {
       if(data1[i,1] == data2[j,1] & data1[i,3] == data2[j,3]){
         difference[i,1] = data1[i,1]
         difference[i,2] = data1[i,3]
         difference[i,3] = data1[i,6]-data2[j,7]    
  } 
 }
```

This code is obviously far from being complete and I have several issues:

(1) I don't know if it is realizable using for loops/if conditional. If yes, being unfamiliar with R, I'm not sure if I need to put a 'print(something)' at the end of the loops.

(2) data1/2[i,1] is of type character. Hence I'm not sure if

```
    data1[i,1] == data2[j,1] & data1[i,3] == data2[j,3]
```

is well-defined.

(3) The 'difference' matrix/frame should have as many rows as the number of i's and j's where

```
data1[i,1] = data2[j,1] & data1[i,3] = data2[j,3]
```

I do not know what this number is. Therefore I cannot really specify the size of 'difference'.

**EDIT:**

```
   data1 = read.csv("path/to/data1.csv") ## Prices of 157 products each at
   ## 122 time points; (column1=Product, column3=date, column7=price)      
   data2 = read.csv("path/to/data2.csv") ## Prices of 118 products each at
   ## 122 time points; (column1=Product, column3=date, column6=price)
   ## the 122 time points are the same for both frames 
   ## But: data1 contains some products data2 doesn't and vice versa
   ## I want to compare prices of the same products at the same time
```

So far, I've done it manually for product X1:

```
   priceX1 = as.data.frame(data1[c(1,122),7])
   priceX2 = as.data.frame(data2[c(5,126),6]) ## Product X2 starts at row 5
   differenceX1 <- abs(priceX1 - priceX2)
```

The problem is I'd have to repeat this for all products contained in both data1 and data2.

**RE-EDIT:** `dput(data1)` returns

```
    ...), class = "factor"), 
COMMENT = c(NA, ..., NA)), .Names = c("PRODUCT", "QUALIFIER_I",      
"DATE", "QUALIFIER_II", "QUOTATION_DATE", "PROD_DATE", "PRICE", 
"TYPE", "ID", "COMMENT"), row.names = c(NA, 14400L), class 
= "data.frame")
```

"..." stands for me omitting a long list of products that couldn't fit here.

`dput(data2)` returns

```
     ..., NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("PRODUCT", "QUALIFIER_II", 
"DATE", "QUALIFIER_I", "Data2_source", "PRICE"), row.names = c(NA, 
19161L), class = "data.frame")
```

"..." stand for me omitting a huge list of prices that couldn't fit in here.

Comment: share a reproducible sample of data and expected output you desire

Comment: @joel.wilson I've edited my question. Does it help?

Comment: it won't because we dont know what and where this path is at? you load the dataset and then post the `dput(data1)` , `dput(data2)`

Comment: I edited into my question what `dput(data1)` and `dput(data2)` return. I hope it helps.

Comment: Those are not full dputs, only partials as you use ellipsis (...). Trust us, those weird dumps mean something to us. Provide all of it. Even better, please provide expected output as textual explanation without data is hard to follow.

Comment: I wanted to provide all of it but alone `dput(data2)` had about 50 000 characters too much to fit in the question. But I guess the problem is solved now (cf Answer below).
Thank you guys for the showing interest, and forgive my ignorance.

Comment: "If loops"? I think you have to work on your terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all pairs (i,j) which satisfy your condition by merging the two data.frames:

```
differences = merge(data1, data2, by=c('PRODUCT','DATE'))
```

This avoids for-loops entirely, and you can easily define the new column:

```
differences$Diff = abs(differences$PRICE.x - differences$PRICE.y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was extremely helpful.